# Slack incoming web hook and getting it to work with HTTPPOST

Tags: java, slack

Team, I need help with posting a simple Json request to Slack. I setup the configuration and have the URL to use.  They want me to add `payload={"Text":"Some String"}`

I'm using the following code:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("slackURL");
 httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("payload={\"text\" : \""+message+"\"}","UTF-8");

           params.setContentType("application/json");
            httppost.setEntity(params);
```

ERROR Message:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Response content length: -1
Chunked?: true
```

Response from Slack:

```
Our logs indicate that the content isn't being posted to the payload HTTP POST/form parameter.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("payload={\"text\" : \""+message+"\"}","UTF-8");
```

to

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity("{\"text\" : \""+message+"\"}","UTF-8");
```

(Get rid of the "payload=", since that's not valid JSON.)

Per [the documentation](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks), you have two choices when POSTing to an incoming webhook URL:

1. You can send the data as JSON in the body of the request.
2. You can send a `payload` form-encoded parameter with a JSON value.

You were doing something in between... you were claiming to be sending a JSON-encoded body (via `Content-Type: application/json`) but you weren't sending valid JSON. (You were sending something that looked more like the form-encoded option, though you weren't actually form-encoding it.)

As a side note: I'd strongly encourage you to use a real library to construct your JSON. Doing it by hand is error prone. E.g., if you tried to encode the message `A wise man once said "You shouldn't try to encode JSON by hand."`, you'd get an error because of the invalid JSON you generated.